# Druid - How to escape character in TIME_FORMAT function

Tags: druid

I am testing a sql on Druid console Query. In my result, I'd like to change the __time to be formatted as `YYYY/MM/DDThh` (e.g. 2022/08/24T12) but I cannot find the way to escape `T` in the format string, and get `Error: Unknown exception`

My sql:

```sql
SELECT
  TIME_FORMAT(__time, 'YYYY/MM/ddThh') AS "hour",
  SUM(cost)
FROM my_table
WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' DAY
GROUP BY TIME_FORMAT(__time, 'YYYY/MM/ddThh')
```

I've tried several other common escape word: `/T` `"T"` but all got the same error, and I can't find a documentation for how to do so.

What will be the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that query:

```sql
SELECT __time, 
      TIME_FORMAT(__time, 'YMDD''T''KK') as formatted
FROM "csv-short-v4"
```

I obtained the record you asked for.

[image]

You can find in the documentation more useful information about the SQL implementation for druid:

- [SQL Scalar Functions](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-scalar.html)
- [Date Format Class accepted by Druid](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)